# How to run one script after another in Apple Script

Tags: ffmpeg, applescript, itunes, m4a

I'm trying with Apple Script to run three different scripts that would alow me to:

1. Convert a purchased m4a file into an "anonymized" m4a file and extract its artwork (with ffmpeg)
2. Attach the artwork to the file previously converted, since the converted file won't maintain its artwork (with AtomicParsley)
3. Remove the artwork from his path

I don't have any kind of programming knowledge, I've collected different script from the web and tried to make an app that could do these 3 simple task:

```
on open argv
   set paths to ""
   repeat with f in argv
       set paths to paths & quoted form of POSIX path of f & " "
   end repeat
   tell application "Terminal"
        do script "for f in " & paths & "; do ffmpeg -i \"$f\" -acodec copy -y \"$f\" output.jpg; done"
        activate
        do script "for f in " & paths & "; do AtomicParsley \"$f\" --artwork output.jpg; done"
        activate
        do script "rm output. jpg"
        activate
   end tell
 end open
```

The problem is that, when I drop a file on the app, it opens three terminal windows at once and it runs the three tasks in the same time, with the obvious result that the conversion fails: the first task overwrites the input file, and the second script should use the output of the first one as its input file. So I need the three scripts to be executed successively, one after another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it uses the Standard Scripting Addition command `do shell script` to run shell scripts without opening Terminal.app

```
on open argv
    repeat with anItem in argv
        set anItemPath to quoted form of POSIX path of anItem
        do shell script "ffmpeg -i " & anItemPath & " -acodec copy -y " & anItemPath & " output.jpg"
        do shell script "AtomicParsley " & anItemPath & " --artwork output.jpg; rm output. jpg"
    end repeat
end open
```

Comment: it doesn't work: the conversion fails because it runs all the scripts at once

Comment: I changed the second '" & anItemPath & "' with a unique file name and it now works. It didn't work before because of ffmpeg overwriting the input file with its output file, resulting in a failed conversion.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I noticed that you're using the same file for input and output but I thought you have a good reason for that